# How to insert Google API Variable in Rails Link_to - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3

could one kindly tell me how you insert the google api variable in a rails link_to?

- in my view: i have the below link which has my google api [`BIxbTnUeb5e9LiB-tmFDs_eGR22E6dZJUMsFmL51`] within it. (note: not the real api key)

  `<%= link_to(image_tag("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=BIxbTnUeb5e9LiB-tmFDs_eGR22E6dZJUMsFmL51&size=400x500&sensor=false&markers=#{@event.latitude}%2C#{@event.longitude}"), "#{@event.maplink}", target:"_blank") %>`
- in my secrets.yml i have successfully managed to store my google api key in a varible `google_secret_key: <%= ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY"] %>`

> could one kindly advise me how you correctly insert the google api
>   variable in the link? i tried the below but unsure:

`<%= link_to(image_tag("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY"]&size=400x500&sensor=false&markers=#{@event.latitude}%2C#{@event.longitude}"), "#{@event.maplink}", target:"_blank") %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the env variable with #{}:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY']}&size=400x500&sensor=false&markers=#{@event.latitude}%2C#{@event.longitude}"), "#{@event.maplink}", target:"_blank") %>
```

Comment: so strange, this was initially not working and now works perfectly! thank you!